# Flutter: call class method

Tags: flutter

Having a simple class:

```
class MyClass {
...
```

What is the best way to call its methods?

A: `MyClass().method()`

B: Add it `final MyClass myClass = MyClass();` at the end of the class and call `myClass.method()`

Comment: You can do A but not B since I’m B you’ve already instantiated it so you should do myClass.method().

Comment: well yes, it was a typo. So, which one is better?

Comment: I kinda like B since you can use that same instance and call the methods on a single instance, while on A you have to always instantiate in order to execute the method, which may lead to more memory consumption due to the multiple object allocations (giving the GC more work). A is only good for one-offs, so B should be the way to go.